# Displaying graph in R using RenderPlot

Tags: r, plot, shiny, data-visualization, interactive

I have worked on plots earlier. This time I am facing issue with `plot` function.

`UI.r` page:

```
    shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("test"),
  sidebarLayout(
    ),
    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
       plotOutput("distPlot")
    )
  )
))
```

Sever.r page:

```
browser()
output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
plot(cars)
})
```

If i put break point at that line of code it jumps the above script and goes to next line of code. I do not understand why is this code not working. Initially I thought it might be because of data which I was using for display but it is not printing default data set data also.

Can any one tell the possible reason or error in this script.

Even tried using `dev.off()` it throws following error:

> Warning: Error in dev.off: cannot shut down device 1 (the null device)

After using `browse()` above code line:

```
Browse[1]> n
debug at /server.R#8: output$distPlot <- renderPlot(plot(cars))
Browse[2]> n
debug at server.R#52: return(df2)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please add [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Try inserting the command `browser()` before the `plot` command instead of using break points.

Comment: @MrGumble The code is not going inside `RenderPlot`. i.e it is directly moving out of whole set of code. it goes near `output$disPlot` but does not go in.

Comment: A `browser()` placed *before* (outside) the `output$distPlot <-` line is triggered during formulation of the server object, not during user-interaction. It will help immensely if you make this question reproducible, including a full, small, *working* shiny app in your question.